# Why does the following oneliner skip the first line?

Tags: perl

Here is the example:

```
$cat test.tsv 
AAAATTTTCCCCGGGG    foo
GGGGCCCCTTTTAAAA    bar
$perl -wne 'while(<STDIN>){ print $_;}' <test.tsv
GGGGCCCCTTTTAAAA    bar
```

This should work like `cat` and not like `tail -n +2`. What is happening here? And what the correct way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of the -n option creates this (taking from `man perlrun`):

```
        while (<STDIN>) {
          while(<STDIN>){ print $_;} #< your code
        }
```

This shows two `while(<STDIN>)` instances.  They both take all available inputs from STDIN, breaking at newlines.

When you run with a test.tsv which is at least two lines long, the first (outer) use of `while(<STDIN>)` takes the first line, and the second (inner) one takes the second line - so your print statement is first passed the second line.

If you had more than two lines in test.tsv then the inner loop would print out all lines from the second line onwards.

The correct way to make this work is simply to rely on the `-n` option you pass to perl:

```
perl -wne 'print $_;' < test.tsv
```

Comment: The first is good also. But this is more clear. Time to read more from `man perlrun`.

Comment: Or even `perl -pe0` - the thinking person's `cat`!

Answer (score 4):

Because the -n switch implicitly puts your code inside a loop which goes through the file line by line. Remove the 'n' from the list of switches, or (even better) remove your loop from the code, leave only the print command there.

```
nbokor@nbokor:~/tmp$ perl -wne 'print $_;' <test.csv
AAAATTTTCCCCGGGG    foo
GGGGCCCCTTTTAAAA    bar
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove `-n` command line option.  It duplicates `while(<STDIN>){ ... }`.

```
$perl -MO=Deparse -wne 'while(<STDIN>){ print $_;}'
BEGIN { $^W = 1; }
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    while (defined($_ = <STDIN>)) {
        print $_;
    }
}
-e syntax OK
```